# Properties not getting serialized

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, reflection.emit

I generate a runtime class using reflection.emit, the generation of the class seems to be fine as it shows in ILSpy:

```
using indice.Edi.Serialization;
using IQoneEDIParser.Formats;
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("CONTRL"), XmlType("CONTRL")]
[Serializable]
public class CONTRL : FormatBase
{
    private string _syntaxkennung;

    private int _sintaxversion;

    private string _absenderid;

    private string _absendercodeunb;

    private string _empfängerid;

    private string _empfängercodeunb;

    private string _dokumentdatum;

    private string _dokumentzeit;

    private string _datenaustauschreferenz;

[EdiValue("X(4)", "UNB/0"), XmlElement("Syntaxkennung", typeof(string))]
public string Syntaxkennung
{
    get
    {
        return this._syntaxkennung;
    }
    set
    {
        this._syntaxkennung = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("9(1)", "UNB/0/1"), XmlElement("Sintaxversion", typeof(int))]
public int Sintaxversion
{
    get
    {
        return this._sintaxversion;
    }
    set
    {
        this._sintaxversion = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("X(35)", "UNB/1/0"), XmlElement("AbsenderID", typeof(string))]
public string AbsenderID
{
    get
    {
        return this._absenderid;
    }
    set
    {
        this._absenderid = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("X(4)", "UNB/1/1"), XmlElement("AbsenderCodeUNB", typeof(string))]
public string AbsenderCodeUNB
{
    get
    {
        return this._absendercodeunb;
    }
    set
    {
        this._absendercodeunb = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("X(35)", "UNB/2/0"), XmlElement("EmpfängerID", typeof(string))]
public string EmpfängerID
{
    get
    {
        return this._empfängerid;
    }
    set
    {
        this._empfängerid = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("X(4)", "UNB/2/1"), XmlElement("EmpfängerCodeUNB", typeof(string))]
public string EmpfängerCodeUNB
{
    get
    {
        return this._empfängercodeunb;
    }
    set
    {
        this._empfängercodeunb = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("X(6)", "UNB/3/0"), XmlElement("Dokumentdatum", typeof(string))]
public string Dokumentdatum
{
    get
    {
        return this._dokumentdatum;
    }
    set
    {
        this._dokumentdatum = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("X(4)", "UNB/3/1"), XmlElement("Dokumentzeit", typeof(string))]
public string Dokumentzeit
{
    get
    {
        return this._dokumentzeit;
    }
    set
    {
        this._dokumentzeit = value;
    }
}

[EdiValue("X(14)", "UNB/4/0"), XmlElement("Datenaustauschreferenz", typeof(string))]
public string Datenaustauschreferenz
{
    get
    {
        return this._datenaustauschreferenz;
    }
    set
    {
        this._datenaustauschreferenz = value;
    }
}
}
```

For any unknown reason, the only property getting serialized to Xml is the Syntaxversion (the only one which is Type Integer)

Here the serialization method:

```
public static String SerializeToXml(FormatBase toSerialize, Type inType)
    {

        XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            NewLineOnAttributes = true,
            CloseOutput = true
        };

        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(inType);
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlSettings))
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");

                serializer2.Serialize(xmlWriter, toSerialize, ns);

                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas about why the rest of properties are not getting serialised? Thanks in advance!

EDIT_1:
After further tests I copy-paste the generated class and created it as a "normal" type in my project, try again the Serialization method, and work as expected (See EDIT_2)

Can it be a Reflection.Emit problem and/or my runtime assembly?

EDIT_2:
Expected result from the Xml Serialization:

```
<CONTRL>
  <Syntaxkennung>UNOC</Syntaxkennung>
  <Sintaxversion>3</Sintaxversion>
  <AbsenderID>9904325000003</AbsenderID>
  <AbsenderCodeUNB>500</AbsenderCodeUNB>
  <EmpfängerID>9900080000007</EmpfängerID>
  <EmpfängerCodeUNB>500</EmpfängerCodeUNB>
  <Dokumentdatum>161007</Dokumentdatum>
  <Dokumentzeit>1723</Dokumentzeit>
</CONTRL>
```

Received:

```
<CONTRL>
  <Sintaxversion>3</Sintaxversion>
</CONTRL>
```

Comment: I can't find `Syntaxversion` anywhere in your code, there is no input xml, no expected result and received instead. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will modify my question regarding to that.

Comment: Sintaxversion is one of the properties in the Generated class. 
Sadly I cannot provide any test case because the code to generate the class is extremely long

Comment: Private properties will  not serialize.  Make them public.

Comment: Ofc, but if you take a look in the class, what you see as private are the backing fields for the public properties.

Comment: If you want to serialize the type CONTRL why do you hand it an `FormatBase` in your method: `public static String SerializeToXml(FormatBase toSerialize, Type inType)`.

Comment: Because CONTRL is a Runtime type I do not have the type to call the method, FormatBase is the base class for it so I do not have to know beforehand the runtime type, I can cast all of them to FormatBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up implementing IXmlSerializable in the FormatBase (Base class)

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            writer.WriteElementString(property.Name, property.GetValue(this)?.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And working as expected.